# Odd Ones Out - Create an Array of Items that Appear an Even Number of Times in Original Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, push

Except, if `67` appears twice in the original array, it also needs to appear twice in the new array.

I tried to tackle [this coding challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/odd-ones-out/train/javascript) by creating a frequency map and then pushing keys with even values into a final array:

```js
function oddOnesOut(nums) {
 let map = {};
 nums.forEach((value) => {
  if (!map[value]) {
   map[value] = 0;
  }
  map[value] += 1;
 });
 let final = [];
 for (let key in map) {
  if (map[key] % 2 === 0) {
   final.push(key);
  }
 }
 return final;
}

console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
```

But of course, this returns `[67]`, when I want it to return `[67, 67]`. I don't know how to push they key (*value*) number of times into the final array.

In this example, the map looks like:

`{ '4': 1, '32': 1, '42': 1, '67': 2, '72': 1, '82': 1, '94': 1 }`

So what is the quickest way to turn this object into an array of items with *even* key-values, where the items appear *key-value* number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter`:

```js
function oddOnesOut(nums) {
 let map = {};
 nums.forEach((value) => {
  if (!map[value]) {
   map[value] = 0;
  }
  map[value] += 1;
 });
    let final = nums.filter(e=>map[e]%2===0)
 return final;
}

console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
```

Comment: Cool I didn't realize that you could access the key-values of an object within the filter method as you've done with `map[e]` - this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array` constructor to create an array of size `map[key]`, and then use [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to fill it with `key`, then push all the elements of the newly created array using the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
function oddOnesOut(nums) {
  let map = {};
  nums.forEach((value) => {
    if (!map[value]) {
      map[value] = 0;
    }
    map[value] += 1;
  });
  let final = [];
  for (let key in map) {
    if (map[key] % 2 === 0) {
      final.push(...new Array(map[key]).fill(+key));
    }
  }
  return final;
}

console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
```

If you want to maintain the order of the original array, you can loop through it instead of looping through the object keys:

```js
function oddOnesOut(nums) {
  let map = {};
  nums.forEach((value) => {
    if (!map[value]) {
      map[value] = 0;
    }
    map[value] += 1;
  });
  let final = [];
  nums.forEach((value) => {
    if (map[value] % 2 === 0) {
      final.push(value);
    }
  });
  return final;
}

console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
console.log(oddOnesOut([75, 68, 75, 47, 68]));
```

Comment: You've answered my question, but unfortunately it doesn't pass the tests on Codewars,  because I didn't realize that the items in the *final* array must appear in the order in which they appear in the *original* array. I.e. testing `[75, 68, 75, 47, 68]` should equal `[75, 68, 75, 68]`. Currently this code returns `[ 68, 68, 75, 75 ]`.

Comment: @HappyHands31 Iterating over the original array will keep the order, check the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the problem description from the link:

> Challenge: You are given a list of numbers. The numbers each repeat a certain number of times. Remove all numbers that repeat an odd number of times while keeping everything else the same.

First create your Map, counting up the number of occurences of each item, then make a Set of those which occur an even number of times. Then use `.filter` on the original array, filtering by whether each item is included in the Set:

```js
function oddOnesOut(nums) {
  const map = nums.reduce((a, num) => (
    a.set(num, (a.get(num) || 0) + 1)
  ), new Map());
  const evens = new Set(
    [...map.entries()]
      .filter(([, count]) => count % 2 === 0)
      .map(([num]) => num)
  );
  return nums.filter(num => evens.has(num));
}

console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
```

Comment: For this problem, the key that we're looking for will change depending on whether or not it appears an even number of times in the original array. We won't always be looking for `'67'`.

Comment: Looks like you should make a Set of the even-counts first, and then `.filter` the original array, to preserve the original ordering

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using a `Map` and `Array#reduce()`

The Map uses the input array values as keys and sub arrays  as values

```js
const oddOnesOut = (arr) => {
  const map = arr.reduce((a, c) => a.set(c, (a.get(c) || []).concat(c)), new Map);
  return [...map].reduce((a, [k, v]) => v.length % 2 ? a : a.concat(v), []);
}


console.log(oddOnesOut([42, 72, 32, 4, 94, 82, 67, 67]));
```